# Parcheesi question - only one possible move

Tags: parcheesi

Parcheesi. The rules say" "If either of the two rolls must be forfeited, the player must forfeit the lower number". Question. What if it's not a question of "either" but you roll 5-3 and can only take the 3?

Answer (score 1):

If you can only use the lower number, you are free to do so (and indeed must do so).

Note the "citation needed" on that one rule you're quoting on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi). Likely the source for that includes clearer text to the handling of the rule. It means if it is possible to use either of the dice but not both, then the player must use the higher number.

It cannot mean that if you cannot use the higher number that you would somehow be prohibited from using the lower number.

That is not a universal rule, however. The [source cited](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Parcheesi_%282001%29.pdf) just above that uncited rule on wiki says only that:

> If you cannot move by the count of both dice, you may move one pawn by the count of **either one** of the dice.

The "must use the higher if possible" rule, given its lack of sourcing, should probably be treated as a house rule.

Comment: (I've updated the wiki entry to reflect the available rules. If someone finds a different source that requires using the larger of the two, let me know and I'll add that info to the wiki.)